# GitHub security issue in a repository

Tags: git, github

I'm facing an issue. I recently invited a friend to work on the same project. So he made some changes and created a pull request then I accepted it. After that, I see these security issues appearing in the repository. How can I fix it and how can I avoid these issues next time?

Edit: I don't know if the above is the issue. I also made the project public and uploaded it in codesandbox. It has api key inside it. So I don't know where the issue came from and how can I solve it?

[image: githubissue]

Comment: Consider reading the documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/managing-vulnerabilities-in-your-projects-dependencies/configuring-dependabot-security-updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know if the above is the issue.

If you are at the beginning of your collaboration with your friend, you might consider hard-resetting your `main` branch to the commit *before* the merged PR, and force-pushing it.
Then see if the alerts persists.

From there, you can read "[About alerts for vulnerable dependencies](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/managing-vulnerabilities-in-your-projects-dependencies/about-alerts-for-vulnerable-dependencies)" and start fixing those.

---

As a workaround, the [OP ErDevFy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13721126/erdevfy) proposes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749260/github-security-issue-in-a-repository/68753122?noredirect=1#comment121508597_68753122):

> I did `yarn why MyDependency`, so it would give me the dependency version.
> I had like 4 glob-parent dependency versions, so I checked for the version and removed the old ones.

Comment: I'm at the beginning of the collaboration but I want to stop collaborating. I won't be collaborating more. Sorry, but I didn't understand `hard-reset main`. Do mean I should start the project from scratch or what?

Comment: @ErDevFy No, simply `git switch main`, then `git reset --hard <aCommitBefore ThePR>`, then `git push --force`: to see if the warnings persists when the analyzed code is the one *before* accepting the PR

Comment: Thank you for the information. I tried another solution. I did `yarn why MyDependency` so it would give me the dependency version. I had like 4 `glob-parent` dependency version so I checked for the version and removed the old ones. I will try your solution next which looks way better.

Comment: @ErDevFy Thank you for this feedback. I have included your alternative approach in the answer for more visibility.